# Issue with awk, bad interpretor

Tags: awk

I have a neuroimaging script that uses a command called mat2det. Example shown bellow:

```
    eTIV=`./mat2det data_path/subject_T_brain.mat | awk '{ print $2 }'`
```

This mat2det command is coded like this:

```
    #!/bin/awk -f



    BEGIN { i=0; } {
    if (i==0) {a=$1;b=$2;c=$3; i=i+1;} else

    if (i==1) {d=$1;e=$2;f=$3; i=i+1;} else

    if (i==2) {g=$1;h=$2;I=$3; i=i+1;} }

    END {

    det=a*e*I+b*f*g+c*d*h-a*f*h-b*d*I-c*e*g;

    printf("%f\t%f\n",det,1/det);}
```

Whenever I try to run ./mat2det, it fails, giving me the error message:

```
    bash: ./mat2det: /bin/awk: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The file has full permissions, via chmod 755 and I'm unsure why this is the case. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Apologies for my ignorance around the topic and if I haven't explained this issue well.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `awk` located at `/bin/awk` on your system?

Comment: Try running `which awk` to find where it lives.

Comment: You may find it `/usr/bin/awk` which is where it is dropped on Ubuntu. In which case your script should start with `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` instead

Comment: adding #!/usr/bin/awk -f  worked! Thank you so much for your help!